# Is ultrasound more subjective than X-ray?

Tags: medical-imaging, x-rays, ultrasounds

There is some discussion on [Ultra-sonic vs X-ray](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24598/ultra-sonic-vs-x-ray) about ultrasound interpretation being more subjective than X-ray findings. Possible sources of ultrasound image quality variation might be the skill of the technician performing the imaging or [technique being used](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1262723/#:%7E:text=116%2C117%5D.-,Discussion,75%25%2C%20specificity%2094%25). Is there any evidence that the interpretation is more subjective as well?

Source:

Goodacre S, Sampson F, Thomas S, van Beek E, Sutton A. Systematic review and meta-analysis of the diagnostic accuracy of ultrasonography for deep vein thrombosis. BMC Med Imaging. 2005;5:6. Published 2005 Oct 3. doi:10.1186/1471-2342-5-6

Comment: I linked "technique being used" to the same source

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer then you may accept it for the future reference.

Answer (score 3):

There are some evidences to prove that ultrasound is subjective, as there are chances of it giving false positive results as the interpretation may vary from one evaluator to the other.

> the interpretation can vary on the evaluator. There is also a higher incidence of incorrectly identifying a mass as cancerous, a false positive..
> [Reference](https://www.cancerquest.org/patients/detection-and-diagnosis/ultrasound#benefits-disadvantages)

> Preliminary data suggest a higher rate of
> false-positive examination results with
> ultrasound than with mammography
> alone.100,104-106 For example, the false-
> positive rate (based on solid lesion for ultrasound) ranged from 2.4% to 12.9%for
> ultrasound and 0.7% to 6% for mammography
> [Reference](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15755947/)

> There are false positive and negative ultrasound results [4]. Although ultrasonography is easily able to diagnose intra abdominal abscesses in cases of appendix perforation, this technique has limitations and is dependent on the user.

> One major issue with ultrasound is its dependence on the operator.
> [Reference](https://www.oatext.com/diagnostic-value-for-imaging-studies-radiography-ultrasound-and-ct-scan-in-pediatric-appendicitis-in-compare-with-adults.php#gsc.tab=0)

> However, ultrasonography is limited by the fact that it is user dependent.2,3 This means that the quality of the images obtained and their accurate interpretation depend on the experience and knowledge of the sonographer.
> [Reference](https://www.vetfolio.com/learn/article/basic-principles-of-ultrasonography)

So these are some of the evidences proving that ultrasonography is subjective and the interpretations depend on the physician's experience and knowledge.

However, to conclude I will say that though I have given evidences of ultrasonography to be subjective (not **compared** to x ray) in general.
I didn't compare with x ray imaging.
Both of these modalities have their own advantage and limitations.

> There is no competition between these two techniques, but it must be the physician that has to choose the better one, knowing advantages and limitations of each one, case by case.

Comparing the inter rater reliability as in [this](https://mrmjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s40248-019-0171-x) between x ray and ultrasound proved the above statement.

Comment: [Even a highly objective test (i.e. a lateral-flow pregnancy test) has a false-positive rate > 0](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7119943/). In order to measure objectivity, you would have to compare [interrater reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) of ultrasounds vs x-rays to find out which is more objective.

Comment: @Narusan thanks for pointing this out :) I have edited my question